# Broke Amazon Workspace Client By Using Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: remote-desktop, amazon-web-services, workspace

While I was logged into my Amazon Workspace via the Amazon Workspace Client for Windows 10, I attempted to login using my RDP (Remote Desktop Connection) app. I opened the RDP from the same machine that I had my Amazon Workspace client open on- not the Workspace itself. For lack of a logical explanation, we'll just say that I was curious to see what would happen.

Well, it kicked me out of the Amazon Workspace Client but successfully logged in via RDP. But now, despite efforts of restarting the Workspace or my physical computer, I cannot access my Workspace through the Client; it'll only log in by RDP. The RDP connection sucks compared to the connection I had using the Amazon client. Additionally, RDP won't fullscreen the way that the client will, so I really would like to connect using the Workspace client again.

When using the client to attempt to login to the Workspace, it'll hang on the connecting animation (the two arrows going around in a circle) while saying "Connecting". The client will then briefly go full screen with the connection tools but with a blank interface as can be seen in the image below,

[Amazon Work Space - Stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5U9L.png)

Then the client goes back into a smaller window size, saying "Thank you for using Amazon Workspaces." as if I had intentionally logged out.

My RDP connects successfully- which is how I managed to restart the Workspace. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I retrieved a solution through Amazon support:

1. Log in to the workspace from RDP
2. Open the following file for editing as an administrator: C:\Program Files\Amazon\Skylight.applications

   If the file isn't showing, please hit ALT to show the menu bar on windows explorer. Then select Tools--> Folder Options. Select the "View Tab" and select the radio button "Show Hidden Files and Folders".
3. Change the version of PCoIP_agent_installer_cmd to 1.6. Do not modify SkyLightWorkspaceConfigService version.
4. Save the file.
5. Reboot the workspace from the workspaces console. The system will think that an older version of the PCOIP agent is installed and will update the driver.

Get a coffe while your Workspace reboots; it takes a while.